# How can I use ggplot in R with data columns from the vector?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the problem with the `ggplot`.

The data samples:

```
> data
[1] "KemData"
> depVal
[1] "Урожайность т/га"
> facVal1
[1] "Предшествующая культура"
```

When I try to build a plot with the following parameters:

```
ggplot(get(data), aes(fill=as.name(depVal), y=as.name(depVal), x=Год))
```

It gives me the following error:

```
 Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type name. Defaulting to continuous.
    Error: Aesthetics must be valid data columns. Problematic aesthetic(s): y = as.name(depVal), fill = as.name(depVal).
```

But if I avoid using `as.name`, then ggplot won't work with double quotes as an input.

I also tried to replace quotes with `gsub` but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Try with e.g `fill = .data[[depVal]]` using the `.data` pronoun from `rlang`.

Comment: `aes_string()` or even `aes_()` rather than `aes()` is probably what you're looking for - see the examples in `?aes`